# Iterate through each row in a PySpark Frame and return the distinct count of users operating +-5 minutes outside of the timeframe identfied

Tags: python, pyspark

I have an original function from pandas which worked perfectly for my use case, however it only worked on a small dataset. My current dataset is 50+MM rows, which Pandas is unable to handle.

As stated in the title the goal behind the function is to Iterate through each row in a PySpark Frame and return the distinct count of users operating +-5 minutes outside of the timeframe identified in each row. e.g if an user completes a task at 2021-02-04 12:44:33, i want to know the number of distinct individuals that also completed the same task + and - 5minutes from this user completing the task. This would need to be checked for every row in the dataframe.

My original python code for pandas was as follows

```
def workers(s):
#get unique count of employee id working on process/function where start_time after amended_start and end_time after amended_end.
if s.tracking_type == 'indirect':
    balancedate = s.balancedate
    process = s.process_name
    function = s.function_name
    start_time = s.start_date_utc
    end_time = s.end_date_utc
    amended_start = s.start_date_utc - datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    amended_end = s.end_date_utc + datetime.timedelta(minutes=5)
    t = df2_mer[(df2_mer['balancedate']==balancedate)&(df2_mer['function_name']==function)&(df2_mer['process_name']==process)&(df2_mer['start_date_utc'] >= amended_start)&(df2_mer['end_date_utc'] <= amended_end)&(df2_mer['tracking_type']=='direct')].employee_id.nunique()
    return t
```

My Attempted PySpark Modification:

```
def workers(s):
    #get unique count of employee id working on process/function where start_time after amended_start and end_time after amended_end.
        balancedate = s.balancedate
        process = s.process_name
        function = s.function_name
        amended_start = s.start_date_convert - f.expr('INTERVAL 5 MINUTES')
        amended_end = s.end_date_convert + f.expr('INTERVAL 5 MINUTES')
        t = df3.filter((f.col('balancedate')==balancedate))\
            .filter(
            (f.col('function_name') == function) & f.col('start_time_convert') > amended_start & f.col('end_time_convert') <= amended_end).select(countDistinct('employee_id'))
        return function
```

However, upon attempting to run the same/similiar code in PySpark (edited for filters), I am hit with a Could not serialize object error as a result of including a dataframe in the function.

I am not sure how to proceed to achieve my objective, whether i can use the same methodology as in Pandas or I would need to use a completely different methodology.

Comment: Trying looking into pyspark Window function.

Comment: please post your sample input and expected output, that would be easier to provide suggestions